How do you change the Q of an inductor in LTspice?
I would like to know how I can change the Q of an inductor in LTspice.

If you right-click on the inductor symbol, a dialog box will appear where you can either add series or parallel resistance. You could add external resistance, but adding the resistance components in the dialog box is more efficient computationally.

Either use an ideal inductor and add a series resistor with it. More resistance equals lower Q. Or, use a real inductor, and modify the Rdc (dc resistance). For reference: Q = (2pif*L)/R = XL/R

At what frequency?
If you're doing a narrow-band simulation, then ESR or EPR (effective series/parallel resistance) will suffice.
For other applications, you may need both: ESR to model DCR, EPR to model core loss (and additional series AC loss).  This is typical when the bandwidth is low (a few octaves) but DC or low frequencies must also be included.
In general, the Q of a reactive component varies with frequency, and one single figure is not meaningful.  Note that inductors are measured for Q at a specific test frequency, and DCR is given, and that's usually it.  Occasionally they do provide a Q curve (vs. frequency) -- a much more subtle, and general, description of performance.
To more fully model an inductor, across all frequencies, more elements are required.  There are many ways this can be constructed, and methods to solve for it; I won't go into detail here, but you may find this useful for additional reading:
Calculators: Coilcraft SPICE Model Converter | Seven Transistor Labs
This page on my website also includes a calculator, with which to convert, create and compare models from one manufacturer.  A purpose mostly obsolete, as they now provide compiled models; but these parameters are still available, and can be used as a shorthand and reasonably accurate description of applicable parts.
In general, the best option is to find a SPICE model direct from the manufacturer, and also verify it yourself for accuracy.  Whether by inspection, or virtual measurement; and, if sufficient data are not provided in the datasheet, then comparing to your own measurements.  Beware that model accuracy varies wildly, from perhaps even a naked L, to a basic RLCR model (can have correct Q at up to 3 frequencies), to a properly nuanced model like this.
Further keep in mind, for cored types, saturation (nonlinearity) is never modeled -- or at least, I've never seen it in the wild (aside from what I've created myself).  You generally want to operate in the linear range anyway, so this should be fine, but keep this in mind when doing pulsed simulations, or when working with ferrite beads (which can saturate at quite low currents).
